# Count cells with specific value - Threading communication

Tags: c#, multithreading, excel

I need to know the number of rows, which have specific value ("DE" or "CH" or "AT") in a specific column (column "C")

At the Moment I'm working with a for-loop, this works, but the problem is, that my program needs nearly 10 minutes to get through the 40k rows of my excel sheet

Is there a way to get this information faster?

EDIT:

I have the Problem now, that I have 3 Threads which work with the same Excelsheet, it's no Problem, when I wait for the "//MessageBox.Show("Es gibt " + Convert.ToString(count) + " Verträge für " + searchword + "!");" for all threads and click OK when all of them are ready.
When I don't wait for it, I get 2 prompts from Excel(picture below) and the Programm crashes.

As I see it, when the first thread is ready, it closes the excelsheet and App and the other threads have problems with that or something?
When the Programm Crashes it says "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AC472" (commented)
Any idea?

Next Question is: To get information from the Thread to the main Form, I use a .txt file, is there any good way to get information back to the main Form or let the threads communicate with each other? This conclusion is not really good :/

[image: ExcelPrompt]

```
    class RowCheckThread
{
    public RowCheckThread()
    {
    }

    public void asdf()
    {
        string localrow = row;
        string localsearchword = searchword;
        string localfile = file;
        Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook ExcelWorkBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(localfile);
        Excel.Sheets ExcelSheets = ExcelWorkBook.Worksheets;
        Excel.Worksheet Sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)ExcelWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        Excel.Range allCellsInColumn = Sheet.get_Range(localrow + ":" + localrow);
        //
        Excel.Range usedCells = allCellsInColumn.Find(localsearchword, LookAt: Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole, SearchOrder: Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, SearchDirection: Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext);//Sucht ersten wert mit searchwort
        string firstFound = usedCells.get_Address();
        Excel.Range next = allCellsInColumn.FindNext(usedCells);
        string nextFound = next.get_Address();

        int count = 1;
        while (nextFound != firstFound)
        {
            next = allCellsInColumn.FindNext(next);//Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AC472
            nextFound = next.get_Address();
            count++;
            if (KeepAlive == false)
            {
                ExcelWorkBook.Close();
                ExcelApp.Quit();
                return;
            }
        }
        //MessageBox.Show("Es gibt " + Convert.ToString(count) + " Verträge für " + searchword + "!");
        ExcelWorkBook.Close();
        ExcelApp.Quit();
        string path = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "test.txt";
        int wert = 0;
        if(File.Exists(path))
        {
            StreamReader myFile = new StreamReader(path, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
            wert = Convert.ToInt32(myFile.ReadToEnd());
            myFile.Close();
        }
        wert = wert + count;
        StreamWriter tempfile = new StreamWriter(path);
        tempfile.Write(wert);
        tempfile.Close(); 
    }

    public string row { get; set; }
    public string searchword { get; set; }
    public string file { get; set; }
    public bool KeepAlive { get; set; }




}
```

Comment: post your loop code so we can help

Comment: Not enough information. There are no faster loops than a for loop unless you can work on your information asynchronously, in such a case, employ Parallel.For().

Comment: I didn't want a faster loop, but another solution.
The Answer from Gun works, it needs 44Seconds now, thats ok for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're automating Excel anyway, you might as well use `WorksheetFunction.CountIf`.

Using this function, you just give the range and the match criterion.

The call will look something like this:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(yourRange, "DE");
```

I'd be surprised if this took more than a few seconds for a 40,000 cell range.

The documentation for the function is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheetfunction.countif.aspx).

Comment: What is "yourRange" and which format does it need? I can't find anything on google.
and given the code above, is it `ExcelApp.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(yourRange, "DE");` ?

Comment: It's a `Range` object. See the link in my post for documentation on this function.

Comment: Great! Glad it works. In that case, you could consider upvoting / marking it as the right answer! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Jochot try the following code which searches in the second column for the keyword "DE"

```
        Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook ExcelWorkBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"E:\test.xlsx");
        Excel.Sheets ExcelSheets = ExcelWorkBook.Worksheets;
        Excel.Worksheet Sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)ExcelSheets.get_Item("Sheet1");
        Excel.Range allCellsInColumn = Sheet.get_Range("B:B");
        Excel.Range usedCells = allCellsInColumn.Find("DE", LookAt: Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole, SearchOrder: Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, SearchDirection: Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext);
        string firstFound = usedCells.get_Address();
        Excel.Range next = allCellsInColumn.FindNext(usedCells);
        string nextFound = next.get_Address();

        int count = 1;

        while (nextFound != firstFound)
        {
            next = allCellsInColumn.FindNext(next);
            nextFound = next.get_Address(); 
            count++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Search Found in {0} Rows",count);

        ExcelWorkBook.Save();
        ExcelWorkBook.Close();
        ExcelApp.Quit();
```