# How to count the number of result in range.search

Tags: c#, excel

I'm running the code as shown below. If my input is "Item A", and there are at least 5 "Item A" in my range, how do I count the number of result that is in that range?

I tried `itemfound.Count`, which the output is a consistent 1, regardless the number of number is has.

```
string a = "C" + nInLastRow.ToString();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range finditemrange =
    Main_Menu.mainitemworksheet.get_Range("C1", a);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range itemfound = finditemrange.Find(itemComboBox.Text,
    misValue, Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
    Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext,
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you don't work with the `Find` function correctly. The `Find` function finds the first occurrence, not all occurrences. To learn how to work with `Find`, and how to find all occurrences, you can look here [How to: Programmatically Search for Text in Worksheet Ranges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4x1k99a.aspx)

Secondly, **a better approach** to count occurrences would be to simply use the **`CountIf`** Excel function.

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(...);
```

It is all mentioned in this question as well [Count cells with specific value - Threading communication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22229731/3848861)